# How to href my ruby code in an html

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, href

I currently have the code below in my html which gets sent as an email. I would like for it to say here as a hyperlink. I have seen and know how to do `link_to` but I do not think that would work in html format or if it does I am not sure how to do it properly.

This code directs the user to a link in my web app with a parameter.

```
 <%=landlord_page_url(@user)%>
```

Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using ActionMailer - if so the corresponding views can certainly use the view helper methods such as `link_to landlord_page_url(@user)`

Comment: @David Yes I am. Could you please explain to me how this would be done?

Comment: You just create the view in the normal way ... not sure how to help without knowing how far you got ... You have an ActionMailer ... do you have methods defined in it with corresponding views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so assuming you have an ActionMailer called MyMailer, with a single method send_link. Just as you would for a controller action, set any instance variables within the send_link method to be used by the email view for rendering.

***app/mailers/my_mailer.rb***

```
class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'myemail@mydomain.com'

  def send_link(user, host)
    @user = user
    @host = host

    mail(to: user.email, subject: "Here is your link")
  end
end
```

Next create a view for this just as you would for a controller actions views and write your html with any necessary erb.

**app/views/my_mailer/send_link.erb**

```
<p>Dear <%= @user.forename %>,</p>

<p>Here is your link</p>

<p><%= link_to 'Click Me', landlord_page_url(@user, host: @host) %></p>
```

And you are done.

Comment: Thank you, I was about to add my own answer, the solution I found is much like yours. Mine was `<%= link_to "Here", landlord_page_url(@user) %>`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, you just need to [supply a host to use to generate the URL](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#class-ActionMailer::Base-label-Generating+URLs).

I think the easiest way to do so is with something like this:

*application.rb*

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
  host: "#{ secrets.uri['host'] }#{ ":#{ secrets.uri['port'] }" if secrets.uri['port'].present? }",
  protocol: secrets.uri['protocol'] }
```

*secrets.yml*

```
shared: &shared       
  uri:
    protocol: http
    host: localhost
    port: 3000

development:
  <<: *shared

test:
  <<: *shared

production:

  uri:
    protocol: <%= ENV['URI_PROTOCOL'] %>
    host: <%= ENV['URI_HOST'] %>
    port: <%= ENV['URI_PORT'] %>
```